# Infinite Chain of Implication Statements - Can it have a Conclusion?

Tags: logic, set-theory

**First, does an infinite string of implication statements have a conclusion? If so, is there a such thing as a "closure" of such a beast, giving a conclusion?**

I am also trying to determine if the following is valid. I begin with uncountable set S, not necessarily well-ordered. I show $\exists$ a nonempty $A \subsetneq S$ such that property P(A) is true, and that this implies P(B) is true for some nonempty $B \subsetneq A$, and this implies P(C) is true for some nonempty $C \subsetneq B$, and so on. **What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for which this process would "terminate" with a conclusion?** If none, can I modify this general approach to make it conclude (akin to some kind of logical "closure")?

Comment: Your question seem to be too broad; furthermore you need to make the distinction between well-ordered and well-orderable. Assuming the axiom of choice we can always well-order a set.

Comment: I only mention it may not be well-ordered because I rely, in no way, on any ordering, as only the existence of these sets is proven. Anyway, the third paragraph is the most important to me and the most specific. I just would like to know if the decreasing sequence of subsets "ends" at some subset.

Comment: I was talking on the third paragraph being too broad. Transfinite recursion is equivalent to the schema of replacement. If you don't have $\sf ZF$ you can't really do transfinite recursion. If you have the axiom of choice then you can prove the existence of well-ordered, and otherwise it would be very wise to state that as well, because so many things are ill-behaved when the axiom of choice goes missing.

Comment: Consider $A_k=\{n\in\Bbb N\mid k<n\}$, this is a decreasing chain of subsets of $\Bbb N$ without an "end".

Comment: And if we allow for transfinite recursion, the well-ordering theorem, or the axiom of choice, then does your defined decreasing chain of subsets "end"?

Comment: No, but you can well-order $\cal P(\Bbb N)$ and use that ordering for the recursion.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, if we well-order power set $\mathcal P(N)$, and treat your $A_k$ as elements in this set, then I can use transfinite induction to prove property $P(A_k)$ is true for all $A_k$?

Comment: That is the plan. Yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That definitely answered my question. I did not think of that. Was what I said in my second paragraph all true? I have been thinking about how, for example, removing elements successively from an uncountable set S (which requires a well-ordering and transfinite induction to eventually get $\emptyset$) is different from $\bigcap_{s\in S} (S-{s})=\emptyset$ (which requires nothing special at all).

Comment: This depends very much on what you want to prove, and how you attempt to do it. Not everything requires proofs by successive cases.